# Funding for an Undergraduate Conference

Tags: conference, funding, undergraduate, research-undergraduate, travel

I'm currently an undergraduate international summer research student in Canada and I'm interested in attending a five-day long undergraduate (math) conference, which is being held at a location that is 4-5 hours away by flight (also in Canada, though.) My advisor is able to fund only a part of my travel and accommodation expenses. Is there any other way to get funding for such conferences, especially as an undergrad?

Thanks for any input! I am certain that this conference will be a valuable addition to my mathematical experiences this summer.

Comment: Your department, school, or the conference may have scholarships available for such things.

Comment: If the funding for your visit to Canada came from a source other than those listed by @JonCuster (for example NSERC or some organization in your home country), then that source might also help fund your conference participation.

Comment: @AndreasBlass NSERC does not pay students directly for conference participation.  Travel is reimbursed through the supervisor’s Discovery Grants or other various programs inaccessible to summer students (especially international).   If the student is on a Mitacs internship, the internship does not include funds for conferences.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Good guess, it's Mitacs!

Comment: Two possible ways: (1) "**CrowdFunding**" or (2) "**GoFundMe**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible although I would not get my hopes up.  As a summer intern, you cannot so easily go to the local student union or the Dean and ask for support.

Step 0 is to figure out if “local” (i.e. Canadian) undergraduate students have all their expenses paid when they attend an event as participants rather than giving a talk or presenting a poster.

Now… you may ask the conference organizers if they can provide you with some help, maybe in the form of a discount on registration or maybe the event has student funding (not clear if that would apply to international students but no harm in asking).

If the event is held at a big shop, like PIMS or Fields or CRM, then maybe ask the institute directly.

(Disclaimer: I have no idea how this works for students attending math conferences in Canada, so I may send you on wild goose chases.)